# Netsuite SuiteScript Caching Issue

Tags: caching, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have deployed my RESTlet script (suitescript 2.0) and calling from my c# application. Initially script deployment status was "Testing" and any changes made in script were getting reflected in my c# application (as desired result). Just before some time I have changes deployment status "Release" now when calling script from c# after making some changes in script, my c# application still gets result of old script.

I have tried switching deployment status to Testing, clearing browser cache but no luck.

Same issue discussed here:

http://blog.prolecto.com/2015/12/06/netsuite-restlet-and-suitelet-application-caching-expiration/

Can anyone suggest me some solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is release but not available to any employee/subsidiaries/roles/etc.

On deployment of your script you will have to set the Audience.
Navigate to Audience subtab on deployment page of your REST and select the required audience and Save it.